# How can use the Word API to programmatically open a document with the Bookmark at the top of the page?

Tags: c#, winapi, ms-word

Using the following code to open a Word document at a bookmark

```
 Object readOnly = true;
                Object isVisible = true;
                Object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

                wordApp.Visible = true;
                wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                object bookmarkName = BookMarkName;
                if (wordDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkName.ToString()))
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Bookmark bookmark = wordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkName);
                    bookmark.Select();
                  }
```

The Word document shows the bookmark, but not at the top of the page. Is there a way of showing the Bookmark at the top of the page as it is shown using Goto-> Bookmark?

The code suggested in StackOverflow Question

> How do I use the Microsoft Word API and Bookmarks feature to programmatically open a Word document to a specific location?

which is

```
Object item = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToBookmark;
                    Object whichitem = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst;
                    Object count = 1;
                    Object name = BookMarkName;
                    wordDoc.GoTo(ref item, ref missing, ref missing, ref name);
```

does not work and gives all the errors described in the post.

Answer (score 0):

**GotoBookmark in MS Word**

In pascal work this code:

```
 procedure GotoBookMark(name:string);
var d1,d2,d7,d8:olevariant;
begin
d1:=name;
d2:=  wdGoToBookmark;
d7:=unAssigned;
d8:=unAssigned;
try
WA.selection.GoTo_(d2, d7,d8,d1);
except
end;
end;
```

Where `name` name of bookmark;

`wa` is `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wa= new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();`

**open document MS Word**

```
procedure OpenWordDoc(Name:string);
var FileName,Visible,newtemplate,documenttype:olevariant;
begin
FileName:=Name;
newtemplate:=false;
documenttype:=0;
visible:=true;
WA.Documents.Add( FileName,newtemplate,documenttype,visible);
end;
```

Comment: How is the document to be opened specified?

Comment: add open document procedure

Comment: About first question. I don't understand what mean 'but not at the top of the page'?

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, since Word VBA isn't really screen-oriented. The following code does work on my screen, but you'd need to test to be sure it works in other configurations. You might need to adjust the "fudge factor" (the literal 40). In any case, though, it should get the bookmark near the top of the screen, within a line or so.

The Window.GetPoint method returns the position in pixels of the Range - it's a Windows API method that's been brought into VBA, which is why you have to pass in the variables, which are then populated with the values.

The Window height less the usable height, plus the "fudge factor" gives you the position in *points* of the visible top of the document. The Window is scrolled line-by-line until the position returned by GetPoint is no longer greater than this position.

```
Sub ScrollBookmarkTopOfPage()
    Dim rng As word.Range
    Dim pxLeft As Long, pxTop As Long, pxWidth As Long, pxHeight As Long
    Dim winUseHeight As Long, winHeight As Long, pos As Long

    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("test").Range

    ActiveWindow.GetPoint pxLeft, pxTop, pxWidth, pxHeight, rng
    'Debug.Print pxLeft, pxTop, pxWidth, pxHeight
    winUseHeight = ActiveWindow.UsableHeight
    winHeight = ActiveWindow.height
    pos = winHeight - winUseHeight + 40
    Do While PixelsToPoints(pxTop) > pos
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll
        ActiveWindow.GetPoint pxLeft, pxTop, pxWidth, pxHeight, rng
    Loop
    rng.Select
End Sub
```